# Generate Dynamic templates(form elements) in Laravel Blade from the PDF template | Laravel | dompdf | FPDF

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, fpdf, dompdf

I have a Laravel application and also I have many PDF templates. I want to generate the form's element(*in blade template*) from the selected ***PDF template***.

In my PDF it will have the form so what I want when someone opens a URL then I want to generate form elements from a specific PDF template(*based on condition but for testing, we can skip condition and use sample.pdf*) and after submitting the form by the user I want to generate another PDF with data(that user entered) and save into storage.

**The new PDF shouldn't further fillable anymore.**

Let me know is possible to generate a blade template from the PDF template or not

I have read about FPDF, DOMPDF, and FPDM but I didn't get any success.

What I have learned so far is that(***correct me if I am wrong***)

- the pdf file should be correct. if it is incorrect then we can repair it by using the PDFtk tool.
- the PDF template should have a fillable form.
- generate the FPDF from the PDF using PHP package.
- Get the user's data and create the final PDF using DOMPDF or any other package.

Comment: Are you trying to create a pdf from a blade template with some dynamic variables?

Comment: No, I already have a PDF template I want to generate a blade template(form elements) from the PDF.